# Get js file as embeded resource from another assembly ASP,NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, embedded-resource, bundling-and-minification

Now I have several MVC4 projects. Some JS files is shared for all of this projects so I put it into dedicated assembly and copy it to each project after changes. 

 How I can put it into this assembly as embedded resource and extract it in my projects to use it with MVC4 bundling? (Is there any way to get files as a Bundle object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can put it into this assembly as embedded resource and extract
>   it in my projects to use it with MVC4 bundling?

You can't. The bundling mechanism doesn't support resources embedded into assemblies. I would recommend you hosting those shared static resources on a CDN (Content Delivery Network) and having all your applications reference them from this common CDN.

You could enable CDN support like that:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.UseCdn = true; //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",jqueryCdnPath)
        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
    );

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually is is possible to bundle embedded resources, but it is not totally trivial:

Basically what you have to do is create a virtualpath provider that references the embedded resource and then bundle the virtual path:

See an example here:
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/aspnet-bundlingminification

Is might also work with a controller that delivers js / css scripts, but I am not sure.

Peter